# Warning: mysqli::reap_async_query(): Connection not opened, clear or has been closed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to do some testing with async queries. I'm getting this result:

```
Array ( [0] => 2017-11-28 11:34:01 [1] => 50 )  
Warning: mysqli::reap_async_query(): Connection not opened, clear or has been closed in /var/www/testasync.php on line 24.
```

I haven't been able to find anything about this warning anywhere. I don't close my connection until the very end of my code. What does it mean?

Here's my code:

```
<?php    
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test");
if (!$connect) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));   
}

// Queries
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM flow01 where datetime = (select min(datetime) from flow01)";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql0, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM flow01 where datetime = (select max(datetime) from flow01)";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql1, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM hum01 where datetime = (select min(datetime) from hum01)";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql2, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM hum01 where datetime = (select max(datetime) from hum01)";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql3, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

// Results
$i = 0;
foreach ($connect as $result) {
    if ($result = $connect->reap_async_query()) {
        print_r($result->fetch_row());
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $i++;
    }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Not something I've used, but the examples seem to use `mysqli_poll` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php) before fetching the results.  Perhaps you have to wait for the results to be ready before reading them.

Comment: See example #4 at that link for how to perform multiple concurrent queries.

Comment: You are probably right about mysqli_poll. I'm trying to figure it out. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you both! That worked. I'm getting good results. I can't figure out how to mark your comments as helpful. Is it because my reputation is too low?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes looking for an answer I'm posting the code I made using mysqli_poll.

```
<?php    
// Queries
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM flow01 where datetime = (select min(datetime) from flow01)";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM flow01 where datetime = (select max(datetime) from flow01)";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM hum01 where datetime = (select min(datetime) from hum01)";
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM hum01 where datetime = (select max(datetime) from hum01)";

$all_links = array();
for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "test"); 
    mysqli_query($connect, ${'sql' . $i}, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
    $all_links[] = $connect;
}

$processed = 0;
do {
    $links = $errors = $reject = array();
    foreach ($all_links as $connect) {
        $links[] = $errors[] = $reject[] = $connect;
    }
    if (!mysqli_poll($links, $errors, $reject, 2)) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($links as $connect) {
        if ($result = $connect->reap_async_query()) {
            $new = $result->fetch_row();
            print_r($new);
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else die(sprintf("MySQLi Error: %s", mysqli_error($connect)));
        $processed++;
    }
} while ($processed < count($all_links));

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

This gives a result of:

```
Array ( [0] => 2017-11-28 11:34:29 [1] => 13 ) Array ( [0] => 2017-12-20 12:11:12 [1] => 12 ) Array ( [0] => 2018-01-12 06:37:10 [1] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 2017-11-28 11:34:01 [1] => 50 )
```

Edit: It seems to pull in results in any order they come which means they are often out of order. I tried adding another column to my table with a number to indicate what table it is then I can sort the results before I display them. If anyone knows of a better way to do this let me know.